# Filling an object (TEXT LETTER) with mantaflow fluid?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Im having no problems running fluid sims and using effector objects and obstacles.. however.. I dont seem to be able to get it to fill a simple mesh?

Has anyone had any experience with this?